# jQuery Auto Scrolling Pause on MouseHover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a help with this auto-scrolling. Please help me to pause the scrolling when Hovering the Mouse over it. Thank you.

```js
/*scroll view*/
$('.scroll').wrap('<div class="scroll-group"></div>');
$('.scroll').css({
  'overflow': 'hidden',
  height: 'auto'
});
$('.scroll-group').append($('.scroll').clone());
$('.scroll-group').wrap('<div class="scroll-wrap"></div>');
$('.scroll-wrap').css({
  'overflow': 'hidden'
});

/*animate*/
var targetY = $('.scroll').eq(0).outerHeight();

var scroll = function(resetY) {

  //animate 기본 동작 변형 "swing" -> "linear"
  $('.scroll-group').animate({
    top: targetY * -1 + 'px'
  }, 6000, "linear", function() {
    $('.scroll-group').css({
      top: 0
    });
    scroll();
  });
}

scroll();
```

```css
.scroll-wrap,
.scroll {
  width: 100px;
  height: 102px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative
}

.scroll-group {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="scroll">content-1<br />content-2<br />content-3<br />content-4<br />content-5<br />content-6<br />content-7<br />content-8<br />content-9<br />content-10<br /></p>
```

Comment: you may need this https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I have no idea how to use this with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdwgvt8f/15/).

I have added `hover` and `mouseleave` function to `pause` and `resume` the scrolling respectively.

```js
/*scroll view*/
$('.scroll').wrap('<div class="scroll-group"></div>');
$('.scroll').css({'overflow':'hidden',height:'auto'});
$('.scroll-group').append($('.scroll').clone());
$('.scroll-group').wrap('<div class="scroll-wrap"></div>');
$('.scroll-wrap').css({'overflow':'hidden'});

/*animate*/
var targetY = $('.scroll').eq(0).outerHeight();

var scroll = function(resetY){
  
 //animate 기본 동작 변형 "swing" -> "linear"
     $('.scroll-group').animate({top:targetY*-1+'px'},6000,"linear", function(){
          $('.scroll-group').css({top:0});
          scroll();
     });
     
     $('.scroll-group').hover(function() { //mouseenter
        $('.scroll-group').stop(true, false);
    });
    $(".scroll-group").mouseleave(function(){
        scroll();
    });
}

 scroll();
```

```css
.scroll-wrap,.scroll {width:100px; height:102px;overflow-y:scroll; margin:0 ; position:relative }
.scroll-group {position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="scroll">content-1<br />content-2<br />content-3<br />content-4<br />content-5<br />content-6<br />content-7<br />content-8<br />content-9<br />content-10<br /></p>
```

Comment: Please explain in a few words what have you done. It's important

Comment: When the user hover the .scroll-group pause the animation. If mouse leave from that element again animate the scroll. This is what i did.

Comment: Not here. In your answer you have to add little explanation

Comment: Please explain me what needs to be add ?

Comment: The user shouldn't read all the stuff that he wrote and you to achieve his goal. Give him, in addition to your snippet, also a little fragment of your work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167712/discussion-between-sarvan-kumar-and-artem-solovev).

Comment: Than you very much Artem Solovev sir. It works perfectly. Just as what i expected. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I have noticed some issue with the code. When I hover the mouse again and again over this, the scrolling speed is getting slow itself. And sometimes page becomes non responding. Because I'm using this code to scroll some images.  Please help if u can. Thanks